# “Object does not match target type” error getting property value from generic Type

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I'm trying to get the value of a property from a generic type in the following method, but I receive the above error:

```
  private static void GetValue<T>(T table)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() != "column").ToArray();
        PropertyInfo[] colProps = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "column").ToArray();

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
            foreach (PropertyInfo cp in colProps)
            {
                if (cp.Name.StartsWith(p.Name))
                {
                    var s = p.GetValue(type, null);                        
                }
            }        
    }
```

GetValue wants the type where the property lives right?

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks!

Comment: Mixing generics with reflection, bad stuff.  Just drop `<T>` and make the argument type *object*.  Less ways to shoot your foot the way you did.  Not sure what the code could possibly do, it does nothing, but using *dynamic* gets to be your next option.  Surely what you really want when you have a "table".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `GetValue` wants an instance or null if the member is static.

```
var s = p.GetValue(table, null);
```

Comment: @user167908 That comment makes absolutely no sense - why are you creating an instance of a type like that?

Comment: slugster is right. You already have an instance you don't need to create another one. if you do that you will only get the default value of your property...

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I'm doing 20 things at once :) I deleted the message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`p.GetValue(type, null)` wants the *instance* of the type that the value is to be retrieved from - in this case you probably want the column but you don't have an instance of it handy (as all you did was retrieve the PropertyInfo's).

You can still select the PropertyInfo's like you are (as a one-time operation) because they apply to the *type*, but you'll also need to iterate the columns and use the appropriate PropertyInfo on each column that fits your criteria (i.e. the column name is 'xyz').

I would suggest some code but your current example is rather mixed up so it's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do.